# Python некорректно возвращает ответ из sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Есть огромный запрос в sqlite такого вида:

```
select ip.ip, hostname, avg_sess_1h, avg_sess_24h, avg_sess_3d, max_sess_1h, max_sess_24h, max_sess_3d, avg_cur_1h, avg_cur_24h, avg_cur_3d, max_con_1h, max_con_24h, max_con_3d from
(select servers.ip from servers where metrics = 1 ) as ip,

(select servers.ip, servers.hostname as hostname from servers left join metrics as metr on servers.ip = metr.serv where servers.metrics = 1 and servers.groups like '%2%') as hostname,

(select servers.ip,round(avg(metr.sess_rate), 1) as avg_sess_1h from servers 
left join metrics as metr on metr.serv = servers.ip  
where servers.metrics = 1 and 
metr.date <= datetime('now', 'localtime') and metr.date >= datetime('now', '-1 hours', 'localtime')
group by servers.ip)   as avg_sess_1h,

...

(select servers.ip,max(metr.curr_con) as max_con_3d from servers 
left join metrics as metr on metr.serv = servers.ip 
where servers.metrics = 1 and 
metr.date <= datetime('now', 'localtime') and metr.date >= datetime('now', '-3 days', 'localtime') 
group by servers.ip ) as max_con_3d 

where ip.ip=hostname.ip
and ip.ip=avg_sess_1h.ip
and ip.ip=avg_sess_24h.ip
and ip.ip=avg_sess_3d.ip
and ip.ip=max_sess_1h.ip
and ip.ip=max_sess_24h.ip
and ip.ip=max_sess_3d.ip
and ip.ip=avg_cur_1h.ip
and ip.ip=avg_cur_24h.ip
and ip.ip=avg_cur_3d.ip
and ip.ip=max_con_1h.ip
and ip.ip=max_con_24h.ip
and ip.ip=max_con_3d.ip

group by ip.ip
```

Если я его делаю напрямую в базе, то вывод такой:

```
172.28.5.17|server1|16.2|16.2|16.2|59|59|59|137.1|137.1|137.1|171|171|171
172.28.5.5|server12|0.0|0.0|0.0|0|0|0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0|0|0
172.28.5.6|server3|16.3|16.3|16.3|59|59|59|137.4|137.4|137.4|171|171|171
```

Если вывожу через python на сайт вот так вот:

```
try:    
        cur.execute(sql)
    except sqltool.Error as e:
        print('<span class="alert alert-danger" id="error">An error occurred: ' + e.args[0] + ' <a title="Close" id="errorMess"><b>X</b></a></span>')
    else:
        return cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()    
    con.close()
```

То почему-то либо тишина, либо только часть данных. Куда копать даже не знаю... Подскажите, кто может знает)

Код вывода:

```
if form.getvalue('table_metrics'):
    import http.cookies
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates/ajax'))
    template = env.get_template('table_metrics.html')

    cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
    user_id = cookie.get('uuid')    
    table_stat = sql.select_table_metrics(user_id.value)
    print(table_stat)
    template = template.render(table_stat = sql.select_table_metrics(user_id.value))                                            
    print(template)
```

UDP

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import funct
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
import os
import cgi
import sql
import http.cookies
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates/ajax'))
template = env.get_template('table_metrics.html')

cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
user_id = 'a026fef7-f1db-4342-99bb-4afa2d744617'    
#user_id = cookie.get('uuid')   
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
template = template.render(table_stat = sql.select_table_metrics(user_id))                                          
print(template)
table_stat = sql.select_table_metrics('a026fef7-f1db-4342-99bb-4afa2d744617')
print(sql.select_table_metrics('a026fef7-f1db-4342-99bb-4afa2d744617'))
#print(table_stat)
```

Comment: Хотя бы выведите в консоль: `print(cur.execute(sql).fetchall())`

Comment: Сейчас там пусто. Но я почистил таблицу с метриками... Когда в базе были данные за 3-4 дня для некоторых серверов, то возвращалась только часть данных, для тех серверов, где статистика собиралась непрерывно 3 дня... я бы понял, что проблема именно в этом, если бы запрос в базе ничего не возвращал, а так такое ощущение, что где-то теряется :(

Comment: Напишите простой скрипт запроса в базу, без веба и сначала с ним поиграйтесь, после того как разберетесь, сможете в проект перенести наработки

Comment: Так запрос же работает, база возвращает... в чем смысл играться?

Comment: Если у вас запрос работает, база возвращает смысл было создавать вопрос тут? :) Мне кажется у вас проблема где-то в другом месте, уже после `return cur.fetchall()`, т.к. не должно быть проблем с драйвером sqlite. Вот простой скрипт, для отработки алгоритма поможет в этом убедиться

Comment: Скрипт возвращает тоже самое, что возвращает база ) Дальше у меня это передается в шаблон jinja2:`{% for val in table_stat %}
 <tr class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">
  <td class="padding10 first-collumn"><span title="{{ val.0 }}">{{ val.1 }}</span></td>
  <td>{{ val.2 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.3 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.4 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.5 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.6 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.7 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.8 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.9 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.10 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.11 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.12 }}</td>
  <td>{{ val.13 }}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}`

Comment: Воот, значит проблема в другом месте, не думаю что код скрипта отличается от того что у вас в вопросе написан

Comment: Не отличается, просто вызывает функцию, я поправил предыдущий вопрос... но понятней не стало, почему в шаблон не доходит? ))

Comment: Не вижу в вашем коде записи в шаблон

Comment: Код выглядит так: `if form.getvalue('table_metrics'):
import http.cookies
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates/ajax'))
template = env.get_template('table_metrics.html')
cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
user_id = cookie.get('uuid') 
template = template.render(table_stat = sql.select_table_metrics(user_id.value))        
print(template)` Вообще странная хрень получается, если я переношу функцию в отдельный файл и вызываю из строки то все норм если из веб, то print(stat_table) показывает `[]`

Comment: лучше в вопрос добавьте, после `UPD`. В комментарии невозможно большой код воспринимать :)

Comment: Добавил ) вообще нечего не понимаю... перенправил вызов ajax, на тестовый файл, в вебе пустой массив, вызываю из строки - все отлично....

Comment: Я уже потерял нить обсуждения и не знаю сейчас в чем проблема Оо

Comment: сейчас проблема в том, что через веб возвращает пустой массив, через командную строку - нормально

Comment: проверьте значение `user_id.value`

Comment: я его вручную прописал, так что он сейчас не влияет

Comment: Прописали в вебе или в командной строке?

Comment: и там и там, сейчас для этого один код использую, напишу в первый пост его